# error C2664: 'CComboBox::InsertString' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [4]' to 'LPCTSTR'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, user-interface

I am trying to do the following:

```
class sig
{
    CComboBox objList;
    void SetDefault();
}
void sig :: SetDefault()
{
    objList.InsertString(0, METHOD_ONE);
}
```

I have defined METHOD_ONE in a different class as

```
#define METHOD_ONE "OFF"
```

And I get the above error.

Can somebody please help me?

Cheers,

Chintan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The most important part is to understand the error**; know what is a `const char [4]`, is the easy part but, what about the `LPCTSTR`?

According to the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> An `LPCWSTR` if UNICODE is defined, an `LPCSTR` otherwise. For more
>   information, see Windows Data Types for Strings.

And the `LPCWSTR` is:

> A pointer to a constant null-terminated string of 16-bit Unicode characters. For more information, see Character Sets Used By Fonts.

First, you must check out what type of encoding are using your program; it seems that you're using `UNICODE`, so in the end you're trying to convert a const pointer to `char`s (the "OFF" constant) to a const pointer to `wchar_t`, and (logically) the conversion isn't allowed.

Then, you can choose the correct string type; if UNICODE is defined, your `#define` must be wide string:

```
// Note the L
#define METHOD_ONE L"OFF"
```

You can also define it this way:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define METHOD_ONE L"OFF"
#else
#define METHOD_ONE "OFF"
#endif
```

Or use the `_T` macro suggested by Roman R. The only that this macro does is to append `L` prefix to the text:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define _T(x) L ##x
#else
#define _T(x) x
#endif
```

In the end, you must be aware of what kind of string are using; but Microsoft is hidding it by using an obscure chain of `#define`s and `typedef`s.