# How to convert const char* to const WCHAR*

Tags: c++, type-conversion, const-char

I have something like this:

```
if(GetFileAttributesW("C:\\Directory")!="INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES") {...}
```

I get error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'const WCHAR*' for argument '1' to 'DWORD GetFileAttributesW(const WCHAR*)'

How to convert `const char*` to `const WCHAR*`?

Comment: `GetFileAttributesW` returns a DWORD, which doesn't usefully compare to a `const char[]`. You probably didn't want to quote `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES`.

Comment: INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES is an integral identifier not a string. You should remove the quotes from around that.

Comment: @Robᵩ Gosh, I really must have some break... Thanks man...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `GetFileAttributesW`, use `GetFileAttributes`. Add `_T` to all const strings, and use `_TCHAR*`. And `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUES` is definitely *not* a string...

```
if(GetFileAttributes(_T("C:\\Directory"))!= INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES ) 
 {...}
```

See [Unicode Programming Summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dybsewaf.aspx).

Comment: Or just use L"" and forget about ASCII builds?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing text literals of one kind of codification with function calls with another kind of codification.

All this confusion is due the obscure chain of `#define`s and `typedef`s that Microsoft puts on his headers.

One of this annoying Microsofts tricks is to declare two function calls differenced with a letter `A` or `W` depending of the project settings. There's a macro that transforms the `GetFileAttributes` to `GetFileAttributesA` or `GetFileAttributesW` if `UNICODE` is defined.

In your case, you're getting rid of the macro and calling the `UNICODE` version directly (the one ended with the letter `W`) but in your call you're using a no-widestring literal, you can fix it easily appending a `L` to the literal (as suggested by other users):

```
if(GetFileAttributesW(L"C:\\Directory")!="INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES") {...}
```

So, if you're calling the version ended with `A`, you can use a no-widestring literal:

```
if(GetFileAttributesA("C:\\Directory")!="INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES") {...}
```

Other way to fix it is using the `_T` macro (Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383963/error-c2664-ccomboboxinsertstring-cannot-convert-parameter-2-from-const)):

```
if(GetFileAttributesW(_T("C:\\Directory"))!="INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES") {...}
```

But if `UNICODE` isn't defined, your original problem will rise again; finally, you can surrender to the Microsoft way of doing things and use all the macros provided:

```
// Note the lack of W or A, it's a macro, not a function call!!
if(GetFileAttributes(_T("C:\\Directory"))!="INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES") {...}
```

Using the two macros (the one that changes `GetFileAttributes` with the `UNICODE` or no-`UNICODE` version and the one that appends the `L` to the literal), there's no need to worry about the project settings because the macros takes this responsability for you.

Edit.

My bad, i almost forget the most important part.

As pointed by other users, you're comparing the return value of `GetFileAttributes` with a text literal; it returns a DWORD and according to the Microsoft documentation:

> A DWORD is a 32-bit unsigned integer (range: 0 through 4294967295 decimal).

So, in the end, you're comparing an integer with a `char[24]`, the comparison is possible but, it will never be true! You must read about the function and how to use it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare the pointers address rather than the comtent!

Check function:   memcmp(...)